# find command: search for files owned by many users in one command

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, find

In Linux, is there a way to do a search for files owned by multiple users (or group(s) of users) with the "find" command?

Something like this?

```
find . -user john, akido
```

Comment: `-o` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `-o` syntax like this:

```
find ./ -user john -o -user akido
```

For further references, check [Linux / Unix: Find All The Files Owned By a Particular User / Group](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-all-the-files-owned-by-a-particular-user-or-group)

If you want to check the files belonging to users of a specific group:

```
find ./ -group name_of_group
```

Comment: I had tried the -o  a while back but im searching for files owned by each users of a sub group which is more than two. I never see to got that to work

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. If they belong to the same group, check what I just updated.

Comment: well its not necessarily a real group in linux just specific users who could be of different groups

Comment: That is not possible with basic `find` command. You can do some tricks, but the most recommendable thing is to use the first expression I posted.

Comment: It may help to add parentheses: `find . "(" -user john -o -user akido -o -user scott ")"`.

Answer (score 2):

A file can only be owned by one user.

You can look for groups with

```
find . -group xxy
```

or if you want to find files owned by john *or* akido

```
find . '(' -user john -o -user akido ')' ...
```

Comment: I meant the second case you stated. Could this be used for more than 2 users?